# Calculate execution time function by function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, performance-testing

I have made a program which has like 6-7 functions. I want to see how much time each function takes so that I can improve the one which is consuming a lot of time.

Also, is it possible to calculate cell-wise also?

Comment: You are looking for [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html).

Comment: Have you looked at [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) ?

Comment: Yes I did. But how to call it function wise?

Comment: If you want to test specific functions - as Luca said - timeit. If you want to get representation of how whole program works: [Python Call Graph](https://pycallgraph.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/index.html) will help.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by creating a decorator function and applying it to the functions of interest.

Here's what I mean:

```
from functools import wraps
import time

def time_this(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.perf_counter()
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time.perf_counter()
        elapsed = end - start
        print('elapsed time: {}'.format(elapsed))
        return ret
    return wrapper

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Test it

    @time_this
    def myfunc():
        time.sleep(.25)

    myfunc()  # -> elapsed time: 0.24919553
```